# PHP - Data not being transferred to next page

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code below which is meant to keep the $_SESSION value when its goes to the next PHP page **'individual_item_page.php'**

**NOTE: I have hard coded the longitude & latitude for the SQL query**

```
<table class="center">          
    <!-- SEARCH BY LOCATION -->
    <?php
    $LOCATION = $_POST['location'];
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT dog_park_name,3956*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((-27.318672099999997 - latitude)*pi()/180/2),2)+COS(19.286558 * pi()/180)
    *COS(latitude * pi()/180)*POWER(SIN((152.8500067 -longitude)* pi()/180/2),2)))
    as distance FROM dog_parks.items having distance < $LOCATION ORDER BY distance;");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); ){ 
        $_SESSION["LOCATION".$i] = $row[0]; 
        ?>
        <tr><!-- Adding the first table row -->
            <th>Dog Park</th><!-- Adding the  table header -->
        </tr>
        <tr><!-- Adding the second table row -->
            <td>
                <a href="individual_item_page.php?location='<?php $row[$i] ?>' " >
                    <?php echo $row[$i] ?>
                </a>
            </td>   
        </tr>                       
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Here is the result in the URL when the script is executed. 
Only showing **"**
[image: Result]

I'm thinking it is because there are multiple items being selected in the SQL query eg: dog_park_name,longitude and latitude.
I need only for the dog_park_name to be followed across to the next page...

Any ideas?

Comment: and that's why when you don't check for errors or start the session, you get no results.

Comment: __increment counter__ missing in for loop

Comment: If your PDO object (assuming this is PDO, not mysqli) is not configured to throw exceptions, it will error silently.  Before any querying, `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` so the query itself will throw errors. You need to be using a placeholder and `bindParam()` for `$LOCATION`, rather than placing a $_POST value in the query as well, as any non-numeric value for `$LOCATION` will break your query (vulnerable to SQL injection).  The loop's syntax appears incomplete.

Comment: add $i++; at the last of the loop before closing loop. You could not increment your counter variable which cause $i set to 0;

Comment: Did you include session_start(); at the top of both pages cos i'm not seeing those in your code

Comment: Why are you quoting the `GET` value? That is probably the cause of your issue yesterday. Also please look at how prepared statements are meant to be used, you are consistently using them incorrectly. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Why are your storing this information in session? This looks like a use case where one would typically just pass a parameter to the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not echoing your `$row[$i]`.

Change:

```
<a href="individual_item_page.php?location='<?php $row[$i] ?>' " >
```

To:

```
<a href="individual_item_page.php?location='<?= $row[$i] ?>' " >
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in passing the url from one page to another. That's why it is not redirecting.

```
<a href="individual_item_page.php?location='<?php echo $row[$i]; ?>' " >
```

Answer (score 0):

From code I am missing an `session_start()` other than that your for is missing `i++`

I think you ment to use something like:

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = $result->fetch()) 
{
    $_SESSION["LOCATION".$i] = $row[0]; 
    echo "<tr>". //Adding the first table row
    "<th>Dog Park</th>". //Adding the  table header
    "</tr><tr>". //Adding the second table row
    "<td><a href='individual_item_page.php?location=". $row[$i] ."'>".
    // line above will give you URL Problems in my opinion
    // since you are adding not replaceing
    $row[$i] ."</a></td>".
    "</tr>".   
}
echo "</table>";
```

Honestly why not paste it in the URL?
Not like you are useing regex to clean up your URL.